# How Widespread are 29 Inch Tall Ranges

Tags: stove, range

We are in the process of moving into a new vacation condo.  The new unit has a 27" wide range in it.  I want to use the nearly new 1 year old 30" range we bought for our old condo.

No problem, figured I would just remove one set of base cabinets, cut the counter (Formica), and slide the new range in.  Easy-peasy.

But, I doscovered that the existing range was only 29" tall, and was set on top of a 5" base to bring it up the height of the counters.

[image]

This is the first time I've come across a 29" tall range like this.  Are they very common?  I don't see what problem they solve as most counter heights are 34", right?

Comment: Someone stowed the warmer(where most people keep their pots/pans) drawer from the bottom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have is a "drop in" range.

They are made to sit on supports that match the toe kick and raise the range to the proper height.  (like the riser it was on.)

Here is an  [instalation manual](https://pdf.lowes.com/productdocuments/ddeb27bd-b356-42d5-8bcd-d687d8edd021/65354846.pdf) for a similar unit.

Comment: I didn't realize there was such a thing.  I've had slide-in ranges & drop-in cook tops (with separate wall ovens), but never a drop in range.